# Strange logf behavior when calculating Poisson packet generation times in Contiki OS

Tags: floating-point, msp430, contiki

I aim to generate packets accoding to Poisson distribution in Contiki Cooja using MSP430 Experimenter board (Exp430) platform (same issue applies to Zolertia Z1 motes which also have MSP430-based MCU). I included the math library and coded the Poisson distribution as:

```
float nextTime = (-2.000) * logf((rand() / (float)RANDOM_RAND_MAX));
```

where the actual formula behind the code is -a*ln(rand) in which rand must be a floating point number between 0 and 1. I created a simulation and tested the generated *nextTime*'s and I realized that it generated 0.000 quite often. Then I broke the code into small pieces to see what values are causing 0.000 to be generated as:

```
float inner1 =(float)( (rand() / (float)RANDOM_RAND_MAX));

float inner2 = logf(inner1);

float nextTime =  (float) (-2.000)*inner2;
```

One of value of *inner1* causing nextTime to be calculated as 0.000 was 0.135. Then I set *inner1* to 0.135 and reloaded the simulation and what I got was *inner2* as -2.2 and *nextTime* as 4.5 as it should be. This confused me, because when I set the *inner2* to a constant value, *nextTime* is calculated correctly. But exactly this value was causing *nextTime* to be 0.000 previously. I'm just really curious about it, why it happens in this way. Btw, I know printing floats in Contiki is not supported and I used two different solutions to print these float values correctly([How to print floating point value using putchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357212/how-to-print-floating-point-value-using-putchar/4361722#4361722) and https://sourceforge.net/p/contiki/mailman/message/25936733/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you can use rand().
In contiki, for generate rand number you need to use `random_rand()`
And include : `#include "lib/random.h"`

Edit : For more explanation :
The code of `random_rand()` :

```
unsigned short
random_rand(void)
{
/* In gcc int rand() uses RAND_MAX and long random() uses RANDOM_MAX=0x7FFFFFFF */
/* RAND_MAX varies depending on the architecture */

  return (unsigned short)rand();
}
```

So it return unsigned short, whatever happen. If the RAND_MAX is not well defined, you'll have an overflow, giving you a signed number. Casting into unsigned do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your reply and help. I think I skipped using random_rand() although in other source files I had used it. Seemingly using the ordinary rand() instead of Contiki random_rand() was causing a problem, which I don't know what was happening in the background. Anyway, it solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers.